# Button control animations using event triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, triggers, storyboard

I want to achieve in XAML using event triggers where button's style (button and text gets bigger) change when mouse enter is triggered. Then when the mouse leave event is triggered, it will get back to it's previous style.

I have already worked out on that but my problem is when a button is clicked, the style for the mouse enter must be preserved unless other button is clicked.

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleX"
            To="2" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY"
            To="2" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
  </EventTrigger>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleX"
            To="1" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY"
            To="1" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
  </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you wanting the button to visually do nothing when it's clicked, or...?

Comment: When the button is clicked, i want it to stay big. So on mouse enter: button gets big. On mouse leave: button gets small again. But on mouse click: button should stay big even if on mouse leave is triggered.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a ToggleButton instead of a regular button and apply your style changes to Checked events instead of the MouseEnter/MouseLeave Events.

Comment: @Chris: I'll try toggle button. But what if I have to add another button and only one button should be toggled?

So when button 1 is toggled (which is scaled) then user goes to button 2 then clicked (which is scaled), button 1 should scale down. Thank you.

Comment: @lionheart Then you want to make them Radio Buttons, which really are just toggle buttons with more logic.

Comment: @lionheart Like VLTII said, if only one should apply the condition at a time then a RadioButton Group is what you want. Keep in mind you can make these controls look like just about anything with the help of Expression Blend, they don't necessarily have to visually Look like a standard radio button, but from what you describe VLTII has your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you for all you comments. They were great and correct but I have to find a way to implement it using the standard buttons (not radio or toggle).

I was able to figure this one out. So, I thought of extending the Control button to add something like a flag to determine if the button has been clicked then handled the OnMouseLeave event.